# Linux desktop search tool that OCRs PDF/TIFF files

Tags: linux, ocr, file-search

I want a Linux GUI application in which I can search my home folder for all documents that contain a particular word/sentence.

- Obviously, it must work with text files.
- It must also work with MS Office and OpenDocument files.
- Moreover, it must work with PDF/TIFF/JPG/DjVu files, even those that are pure images; that means that **the indexer must perform OCR recognition on the content of these files**.

Ideally open source, but up to 50 USD per year per user is also OK.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is *not able to open MS Office and OpenDocument files*, [Paperwork](https://openpaper.work/en-us/) (under the GPL-3.0 license) *does a great job of indexing image files*.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194139/whats-the-best-way-to-search-my-file-system-on-ubuntu-with-instant-results) mentions a couple of software packages.

Let me propose [Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker). From the [page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/WhatIsTracker):

> By using Tracker, you no longer have to remember where you've left
>   your files. To locate a file you only need to remember something about
>   it, such as a word in the document or the artist of the song. This is
>   because as well as searching for files in the traditional way, by name
>   and location, Tracker searches files' contents and metadata.

Tracker is Free Software and should be easily installable. It may already be installed on your system.

You can search for document contents as per this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Tracker does not OCR image files unfortunately. For instance, does it find "London" if "London" is visible when seeing the image "sue-passport.jpg"?

Comment: Ah! I misread. Sorry. I though it's about ORC*ed* files :-/  Sorry for the noise, then.